# Gulp creates folder instead of following path

Tags: javascript, css, sass, gulp

I'm using the script below to compile and then copy my scss/css to another folder. On one of my machines this works perfectly, but on my laptop it creates a new folder instead of going back one folder and then follow the path.

Specific line:

```
.pipe(gulp.dest(PATHS.dist + '../../../httpdocs/assets/css'))
```

On my laptop it makes a folder called "dist.." at the same level as "dist" is, instead of copying the file and then going back one level and enter "httpdocs/assets/css" and paste the file there.

Full code:

```
function sass() {
  return gulp.src('src/assets/scss/app.scss')
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe($.sass({
      includePaths: PATHS.sass
    })
      .on('error', $.sass.logError))
    .pipe($.autoprefixer({
      browsers: COMPATIBILITY
    }))
    .pipe($.if(PRODUCTION, $.uncss(UNCSS_OPTIONS)))
    .pipe($.if(PRODUCTION, $.cssnano()))
    .pipe($.if(!PRODUCTION, $.sourcemaps.write()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(PATHS.dist + '/assets/css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(PATHS.dist + '../../../httpdocs/assets/css'))
    .pipe(browser.reload({ stream: true }));
}
```

Folder structure:

```
Project
  -- dev
    -- dist
    -- src
      -- assets
        -- scss
    -- and some other folders
  -- httpdocs
    -- assets
      -- css
```

Comment: What is the value of `PATHS.dist`? What operating system(s) are you using between the two machines?

Comment: Both machines are on OSX 10.11.4. The value of PATHS.dist is:

# Path to dist folder
dist: "dist"